# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type

Tags: typescript

This is the full error I get when I hover on data[command] in limit-entries.ts

> (parameter) data: dataProps Element implicitly has an 'any' type
>   because expression of type '"hourly"' can't be used to index type
>   'dataProps'.   Property 'hourly' does not exist on type 'dataProps'

darkSkyApiTypes.ts

```
interface dataProps {
  data: {
    latitude: number
    longitude: number
    timezone: string
    currently?: {
      time: number
      summary: string
      temperature: number
      humidity: number
    }
    hourly?: {
      summary: string
      icon?: string
      data: {
        time: number
        temperature: number
        humidity: number
      }[]
    }
    daily?: {
      summary: string
      icon?: string
      data: {
        time: number
        temperatureMin: number
        temperatureMax: number
        humidity: number
      }[]
    }
  }
}

export = dataProps
```

limit-entries.ts

```
import { hourlyLimit } from '../config'
import dataProps from '../API/darkSkyAPITypes'

const limitEntries = (data: dataProps, command: string) => {
  let entries

  switch (command) {
    case 'currently':
      entries = data[command]
      break
    case 'hourly':
      entries = data[command].data.slice(0, hourlyLimit)
      break
    case 'daily':
      entries = data[command].data
      break
    default:
      entries = data[command]
  }

  return entries
}

module.exports = limitEntries
```

I get the error in title. Help!

Comment: Side note: The overwhelming convention in TypeScript is that non-built-in types start with a capital letter. So `DataProps` rather than `dataProps`.

Answer (score 1):

`dataProps` defines an object type with a single top-level property called `data`. Your `data` variable is of type `dataProps`, so you'd need `data.data` to refer to that property. So where you have `data[command]`, you should have `data.data[command]`. (Or change the definition of `dataProps`.)